# Jquery marquee script not working in joomla?

Tags: php, module, jquery, javascript

I want to marquee some content divs with continues scrolling. I create a module then added the jQuery from this url: https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery. This code is working successfully in our local server but not in my Joomla site. My `default.php` is

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet('modules/mod_marquee/css/style.css');
$document->addScript('modules/mod_marquee/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
$document->addScript('modules/mod_marquee/js/jquery.marquee.min.js');
$document->addScript('modules/mod_marquee/js/script.js');?>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid" data-duration='5000' data-gap='10' data-dupilcated='true'>
            <div class="row marquee">
            <div class="span3" align="center">level 2 column and ger more variables</div>
            <div class="span3" align="center">level 2 column</div>
            <div class="span3" align="center">level 2 column</div>
            <div class="span3" align="center">level 2 column</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My script.js is: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing's first:

### do not import an unofficial jQuery library forked by someone!

Now, when importing any script, you should always define the root of your site using `JUri::root()`. You should also use Joomla's `JHtml` method. So replace this:

```
$document->addStyleSheet('modules/mod_marquee/css/style.css');
$document->addScript('modules/mod_marquee/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
$document->addScript('modules/mod_marquee/js/jquery.marquee.min.js');
$document->addScript('modules/mod_marquee/js/script.js');
```

with this:

```
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_marquee/css/style.css');
JHtml::_('script', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js');
JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_marquee/js/jquery.marquee.min.js');
JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_marquee/js/script.js');
```

I'm not sure which version of Joomla you're using by take a look at my [answer on another question to import jQuery properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933)

As for you script, try using this at the beginning instead:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function($) {
```

else try using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro @lodder i follow your procedure i got the result.I simply add this `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` in my script.js.