# how to display Moving text in a website

Tags: joomla-2.5

please visit this link : http://www.sivanadi.com [wordpress]

Below "menu" , you can see moving lines.

How to do it in a joomla site's footer.

please help me to find some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. We are more than happy to help guide you with code and Joomla administration, however we won't write all your code for you. Try something of your own first and then come back if you have issues with your code

Comment: okay, i will try....

Comment: please help me to add some text in footer above "online payment" in this link : http://naadiastrology.info/

Comment: why this tag is not working in joomla footer : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquee_tag.htm

Comment: I created a module and put "bottom-a" and use html editor and paste the code there. but the text is not moving. please help me.

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag is deprecated, do not use it

Comment: than what is the solution to move the text in joomla

Comment: Google >> jquery horizontal scrolling text

Comment: i will try and let you know....

Comment: hi @lodder, I saw your answer in this : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3655/jquery-marquee-script-not-working-in-joomla . But As i am joomla beginner. Can you please explain me in detail, in which file, which code I have to edit to get the "moving text". please help me.

Comment: I installed this extension : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/6677


I installed this extension using : Extension Manager > Upload package file. It's installed successfully.

In Plug-in manager, I enabled It.

Than In Module manager, I created "Moving text" module and in "Custom output" , I entered the code : 

<div class="movingObj">

{text =scrollig text }

</div>

But it's not working here you can visit this link and see in footer http://naadiastrology.info/

Why it's not working or how to use this extension.

Comment: hi Lodder, thanks a lot for your help. some extension worked here.

Comment: how to change moving speed of text? please help me.....

Comment: I noticed you got an [answer](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4832/decrease-the-speed-of-moving-text-in-extension/4835#4835) on how to change the text speed. I understand you're new to Joomla, and we've all been there once, but **please** do a little research before asking (you've posted about 4 separate questions regarding this moving text issue). Google is your best friend, as well as the developers of any extension you install. I suggest you start with a [Joomla Tutorial](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=joomla+beginner+tutorial). If you still can't find answers, we're more than happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get scrolling text is to look for a Joomla extension. The [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) has extensions to achieve lots of nice effects and functionality, and most of them are available for free. It's a good starting point for many of your Joomla-related problems.

I suggest you take a look at this extension: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/6677. Other alternatives can be found here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers

In case you decide to use another code (using [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/FWWEn/)), keep in mind that most editors in Joomla (like TinyMCE) will strip out most of your JavaScript code. The best way to use custom code is to [create your own Joomla Module](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module). It's not hard, but requires some PHP experience.

An easier way to add custom code is to use a [Custom Code Module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules), basically a text module without filtering. That way you can add CSS, JavaScript, PHP and HTML code without problems.

Comment: hi @Johanpw, thanks a lot for reply. as i new to joomla, i have fear to use extension and also I don't know how to take back up in joomla. so i am planning to use jquery as like here : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3655/jquery-marquee-script-not-working-in-joomla. Can you please explain me in detail about lodder answer => in which file, which code i have to edit? please help me....

Comment: Or Please visit this link : http://breakdesigns.net/extensions/moving-text


I installed this extension using : Extension Manager > Upload package file. It's installed successfully.

But when i gave this text is modules = > <div class="movingObj">{text =scrollig text } </div>

It's not working in site.

please help me to find solution to add moving text in joomla.

Comment: I installed this extension : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/6677


I installed this extension using : Extension Manager > Upload package file. It's installed successfully.

In Plug-in manager, I enabled It.

Than In Module manager, I created "Moving text" module and in "Custom output" , I entered the code : 

<div class="movingObj">

{text =scrollig text }

</div>

But it's not working here you can visit this link and see in footer http://naadiastrology.info/

Why it's not working or how to use this extension.

Comment: It seems to be working fine now, but you should hide the module title (in Module manager, set "Show Title" to `No`, and set the width to `300` in the plugin settings if you're going to use it in that position. Don't be afraid of using extensions, that's the best part of Joomla.

Comment: hi @johanpw, please visit this link: http://naadiastrology.info/  I added in footer.

Comment: Thanks a lot , because of you, I learned the positions and all. your answer here helped me lot. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4787/add-text-in-empty-space-in-joomla-corpoboost-theme?noredirect=1#comment8167_4787

Comment: please visit this link, in the footer , you can see moving text :, how to apply css on it, it's not working inside html editor?

Comment: No, you can't add CSS style inside the html editor. You can style the text scroller by adding `.movingObj { /* Your css here */
}` to your css file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... is there any option I can add css style using adminstrator panel.

Comment: how to change moving speed of text? please help me.....