# How to decrease the speed of the moving text in MovingText

Tags: joomla-2.5

I want to decrese the moving speed of text in the [Moving Text](http://breakdesigns.net/extensions/moving-text) extension.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option in the Plugin settings:

Go to **Extensions** >> **Plugin Manager** >> **MovingText**

and there will be an option called **Speed of Text**

The default is set to `2` so simply change the number. I'm sure a decimal will be allowed too.

In the future, when using extensions, can you please always look at the settings and also read the developer documentation before asking as your question may already have been answered.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your help. I will surely do it from next time.